# Remote debugging against a google-tv device using adb and the Xamarin.Android tools in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, adb, google-tv, xamarin, xamarin.android

Playing around with the latest Xamarin 2.0 Xamarin.Android tools.  The only android device I have (other than the emulator) is Google-TV device.  I have connected the adb to my Google-TV, but don't see any way to debug against the remote device using the Xamarin tools in Visual Studio.  Is this possible?  What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but Google TV is not compatible with Xamarin.Android. This is because [Google TV doesn't support the NDK](https://developers.google.com/tv/faq#ndk) (a requirement for Xamarin.Android).

Comment: Thanks!  Looks like I'll have to get my hands on another android device to play with.  I was hoping the Google-TV device would work for simple dev stuff.